# Issue with putting div over another div

Tags: html, css

Before giving negative vote or placing the question as duplicate, please read the issue first.

I'm having some issue with putting one div under another. I know that make people have asked this question here and I've read all of them and also tried everything out, but none of them worked for me.

Everyone days to give `position: relative` to to div and then give one higher `z-index` and another lower. None of them worked for me. So, I'm here for help.

In my project (http://loadtest.isaumya.com/) I have 2 divs i.e.

```
<body>
<div class="conteiner">blah blah blah</div>

<div id="particle-js"></div>
</body>
```

I want to put the `<div id="particle-js"></div>` behind of container, but nothing is working out. So please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have ordered them badly:

```
<div class="container">...</div>
<div id="particles-js">...</div>
```

**invert positions:**

```
<div id="particles-js">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
```

makes sense since you want your full-screen canvas particles to be naturally z-index lower than the latter #container. Precedence rule.

also add this styles to your `particle-js` element:

```
#particles-js{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

If the above still does not helps (it should) add:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Make your `canvas` element `display:block;`**

Result image:

[image]

Comment: Hey man. Thank you very much for answering. But I did that, still not showing like the screenshot you have posted. Check the page again. You will see. I've done everything you have said.

Comment: @iSaumya you did NOT set position:absolute to `particles-js` element. Once I set position:absolute; it's showing well. Make sure JS is not interfering with your styles. Use console inspect element. Play with it.

Comment: @iSaumya note that your element ID is `#particles-js` (with an 's' plural, not `particle-js like you wrote`)!!

Comment: Oh! Sorry it was a typo. but after making absolute, it looks wired. Please visit the page again, you will see.

Comment: @iSaumya ok, now add to that `#particles-js` also `width:100%; height:100%;`

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you man. Love you man. <3 But 1 wired thing is still happening. If you visit the page, you will see vertical scrollbar. Right? But this page does not have content to have vertical scroll bar. Thats wired.

Comment: @iSaumya found the issue. Set `line-height:0;`  to `#particles-js` and you're done! (that's cause the inner canvas is still an inline element, therefore it adds up the whitespace)

Comment: well it actually increased the scroll bar. see now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67806/discussion-between-roko-c-buljan-and-isaumya).

Answer (score 1):

its just a very simple concept you need to remember about position in css

- A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal
  position

  An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first
  parent element that has a position other than static.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oussamaelgoumri/yyozjpef/)

this is how you may solve this problem:

```
<body>
<div class="container">blah blah blah</div>

<div id="particle-js"></div>
</body>
```

and the css

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

#particle-js {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

make the `z-index` higher to wichever element you want a be displayed at the top

Comment: its better to avoid `z-index` values greater than 3-4. using -4..4 is enough

Comment: @lolbas some older browsers have issues with negative z-index. 0-99999 is a living standard ;)