# particle.js overlapping issue (canvas size)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please don't vote as duplicate or invalid!

I am trying to use particle.js with a Bootstrap template for a project I'm working on. I kept the particle-js div right after the body tag and made a container inside the particle-js div which was a parent to the rest of my website's body. After the particles appeared at the bottom of the website, I tried everything I found at:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27679115/issue-with-putting-div-over-another-div

which is a similar problem. But that didn't work for me either, I tried every solution on SO and I've been stuck for two days now.
Any help would be appreciated!

ayrus.org/test/ -> for those who want to see what the problem looks like!

Comment: Please carry over an example or specific code you suspect error on, as I am not going to some seemingly random link.

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that , the error has something to do with the positioning of the elements which i can't carry over due to their length , is there some other way to send my code to you ?

Comment: I fixed some part of the website by making both the div's absolute but it loses its responsiveness as the absolute element started overlapping with the non absolute elements on mobile devices

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix it , the canvas element that particle.js uses was inheriting the height and width from particle.min.js , i searched for 100% in that file and deleted the line which defined the values ! Then i used

```
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

to adjust the size according to what i needed ! 
Hope this helps someone else out!